# Reference to the current object in a lambda expression

Tags: c#

Is it possible to reference to a property of the current object in a Select statement of a lambda expression in Linq?

Example:

```
...
.Select(s => new { 
                    Date = s.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                    Time = s.Time.ToString("h':'m"), 
                    DateTime = s.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") +"-"+ s.Time.ToString("h':'m"),
                    Temperature = s.Temperature,
                    Humidity = s.Humidity, 
                    Device = s.Device.Name, 
                    Message = s.Message 
                })
```

I would like to replace the double call to the `ToString` function by referencing the previously defined `Date` and `Time` properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lambda function, rather than a lambda expression:

```
.Select(s => {
    var d = s.Date;
    var t = s.Time;
    return new { 
                Date = d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                Time = t.ToString("h':'m"), 
                DateTime = d.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") +"-"+ t.ToString("h':'m"),
                // ...
            })
```

Note the extra set of `{` ... `}` braces, (allowing you to have variables local to the lambda) and the `return`.

Answer (score 7):

If you switch to LINQ query syntax (instead of method syntax), you could use the [`let` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) "to store the result of a sub-expression in order to use it in subsequent clauses".

```
from s in source
let dateStr = s.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
let timeStr = s.Time.ToString("h':'m")
select new { 
    Date = dateStr,
    Time =  timeStr, 
    DateTime = dateStr + "-" + timeStr,
    Temperature = s.Temperature,
    Humidity = s.Humidity, 
    Device = s.Device.Name, 
    Message = s.Message 
}
```

Comment: @Star: Indeed; LINQ has strong associations with functional languages.